# `class file has wrong version` after Jenkins upgrade

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

A couple of days ago, I upgraded Jenkins to version `1.643`. Before, we were using Jenkins `1.593`. Starting with Jenkins `1.612`, Jenkins requires Java 7, see [changelog](https://jenkins-ci.org/changelog/), [announcement](https://jenkins-ci.org/blog/2015/04/06/good-bye-java6/) and [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28120). Our Jenkins server has Java 8.

I have a Maven project consisting of submodules.
In the job configuration in Jenkins, I have configured the build to use JDK 1.6.

When looking at the build environment, it's indeed 1.6:

```
JAVA_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/1.6
```

One of the submodules fails to build on Jenkins, with this error:

```
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/<REDACTED>.java:[15,-1] cannot access java.lang.Object
bad class file: java/lang/Object.class(java/lang:Object.class)
class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
```

According to what I can Google, class file version 52.0 is JDK 1.8 while the compiler is expecting version 50.0, which is JDK 1.6. I assuming that class file 52.0 refers to `rt.jar` (Java Runtime) which contains `java.lang.Object` (see also `pom.xml` snippet below).

I have found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180915/class-file-has-wrong-version-52-0-should-be-50-0) (and others that are duplicate of it), but they are all in the context of someone building from their IDE (IntelliJ) or from command prompt, and after reading them, I don't see how I could apply the suggested solutions. They involve setting `$JAVA_HOME`, which is already done by Jenkins.

My question is different because the issue is in the context of Jenkins (and Maven), and only occurred after the Jenkins upgrade. When I execute `mvn clean install` on my own desktop (with JDK 1.8), the error does not occur. If I execute the `file` command on the offending class file, but on the desktop where compilation succeeded, I get `compiled Java class data, version 50.0 (Java 1.6)`. For me, this confirms that my `pom.xml` is (probably) still correct and it's (probably) a Jenkins configuration issue.

That specific submodule has this in the `pom.xml`, which may or may not be relevant:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <verbose />
                    <bootclasspath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So, as you can see, it takes `rt.jar` from the current `$JAVA_HOME` so it can cross compile with a target of 1.6.

I'm a bit lost about the origin of this  Java 8. Before the Jenkins upgrade, we were already using Java 8 on the server and cross compiling with a target of Java 6. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Do I even *need* this? If I comment out

```xml
                <compilerArguments>
                    <verbose />
                    <bootclasspath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
```

in `pom.xml`, I can still cross compile on my desktop and the class files are still version 50.0.

**EDIT**

When I take that part out, the build does not fail any more.
Which means I solved it myself.

I want to change the question to: *why* did it fail in the first place? And why didn't it fail before on Jenkins 1.593?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `pom.xml` to *exactly* how it is described in this SO answer: [Maven release plugin: specify java compiler version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638399/maven-release-plugin-specify-java-compiler-version/11462151#11462151)

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <bootclasspath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</bootclasspath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you can see:

- I explicitly set the `groupId`
- I explicitly set the `version` to the latest version, `3.3`
- The `configuration` parameters are formatted a bit differently.

My educated guess is that the Maven on the Jenkins server didn't pick up configuration inside `compilerArguments` and was only happy when it is directly inside `configuration`. I leave it to the comments to explain how and why, but for me the issue is solved.

Comment: there's really no need to have same content on both the question and as an answer. choose one or the other :)

Comment: What? You jumped in while I was still in the middle of editing. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few errors in your assumptions.

1. `compilerArguments` is [deprecated](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html). It's been [superseded by `compilerArgs`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs).
2. Like you can see from [compiler plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html), `compilerArguments`/`compilerArgs` is meant to be used only for arguments not supported by configuration section itself. As `bootclasspath` is supported, using it in `compilerArgs`/`compilerArguments` section is generally incorrect.
3. `compilerArgs`/`compilerArguments` is only used if [`fork` is set to `true`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs), which was not correct for your configuration.

The third point was probably the most important reason why it didn't work for you. Using `configuration` section for your use case there should be no issues, and indeed based on your question/answer, this seems to be the case.

Also note that `java.home` is *not* `JAVA_HOME`. I've expanded on that on my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279586/java-home-in-maven/15279640#15279640). I'd guess that is related to why you see changes between Jenkins versions.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand it correctly: the `$JAVA_HOME` I found is something that Jenkins knows about *before* it starts a job, but isn't necessarily the same as the JRE/JDK that Maven is using *at the precise moment when the event occured that triggered my question*, because of what the compiler plugin does. I could have set my job to build with JDK 1.8, set the compiler plugin to build for 1.6 with the configuration as in the answer, and I would still have a valid build. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Great. This means I can move some stuff to the parent pom and simplify the other poms.

Comment: test it first though - there might always be something else that interferes with it.

Comment: Of course. That's what feature branches are for! :)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse to clarify: your bootclasspath would still need to point to rt.jar of a previous JDK. So while you can run it on JDK 1.8, you'd still need rt.jar from JDK 1.6 somewhere and then point to it. Unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought already. Makes sense somehow. It's the actual pointing that I am unsure about and experimenting with.